# Vue custom directive does not register

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a custom directive in vue, but is does not working.

my code in **pin-directive.js**

```
export default {
  bind(el) {
    console.log('hi pin');
    el.style.position = 'absolute';
    el.style.bottom = '5px';
    el.style.right = '5px';
  },
  inserted(el) {
    console.log(el);
  },
};
```

Now I'm using in my vue file as below:

```
import { pinDirective } from '../shared/pin-directive';
// some code here
directives: { pin: pinDirective },

<span  class="sale" v-if="selectedPart.onSale" v-pin>Sale!</span>
```

But it does not seems to apply those style on span element.
even it does not log console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line

`import { pinDirective } from '../shared/pin-directive';`

To this ..

`import pinDirective from '../shared/pin-directive';`